# Can't use the BLEU offline

Tags: python, huggingface, evaluate, bleu

I download all the metrics from evaluate and save them on the disk. When I want to use BLEU to evaluate my model's outputs, a bug occured. I can't load the BLEU from local dir, the pycharm give me an error like this:

`ConnectionError: Couldn't reach https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt/raw/master/nmt/scripts/bleu.py (ProxyError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /tensorflow/nmt/raw/master/nmt/scripts/bleu.py (Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy', SSLError(SSLZeroReturnError(6, 'TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:1131)'))))")))`

But I swear I loaded it from the local dir.Here's my code:

`import evaluate`

`metric = evaluate.load(r"E:\evaluate-main\metrics\bleu")`